# onActivityResult not getting called in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, braintree

**code in fragment**

```
 private static final int BRAINTREE_REQUEST_CODE = 777;
    BottomMenu fragment = this;
    public void onBraintreeSubmit(String clienTtoken) {
        DropInRequest dropInRequest = new DropInRequest().clientToken(clienTtoken);
        startActivityForResult(dropInRequest.getIntent(getActivity()), BRAINTREE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == BRAINTREE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                DropInResult result = data.getParcelableExtra(DropInResult.EXTRA_DROP_IN_RESULT);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), result.getPaymentMethodNonce().getNonce() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // use the result to update your UI and send the payment method nonce to your server
                sendPaymentNonceToServer(result.getPaymentMethodNonce().getNonce());
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // the user canceled
            } else {
                // handle errors here, an exception may be available in
                Exception error = (Exception) data.getSerializableExtra(DropInActivity.EXTRA_ERROR);
            }
        }
    }
```

**code in activity**

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

**Problem:**

> I have implemented BrainTree payment gateway with onBraintreeSubmit() method I startActivityResult and catch it onActivityResult but it's not being called in the fragment.
>
> onActivityResult only gets called if I cancel payment but never when payment success or exception thrown

Comment: Check It out https://stackoverflow.com/a/39267399/5773037 This is worked for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onActivityResult is not being called in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-is-not-being-called-in-fragment)

Answer (score 3):

> First you have to call from activity
>   Add below code in your activity

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frameLayout);
    fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call startActivityForResult() with activity instance, then onActivityResult will get in your activity not in fragment. This is the reason for your issue.

Modified the code as below. This will solve your issue.

```
public void onBraintreeSubmit(String clienTtoken, BottomMenu context) {
    DropInRequest dropInRequest = new DropInRequest().clientToken(clienTtoken);
    startActivityForResult(dropInRequest.getIntent(context.getContext()), BRAINTREE_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Comment: i tried like this fragment.startActivityForResult(dropInRequest.getIntent(getActivity()), BRAINTREE_REQUEST_CODE);  but same problem

Comment: That's why i said to change the code like i mentioned above. If you want to get the onActivityResult() in your fragment, then you just need to call startActivityForResult() with out any class's instance.

Comment: i want to call in fragment see edited question? can u reply?

Comment: You want to call startActivity() from your fragment and want to get onAcivityResult() in the same fragment. This is your requirement, is it correct?

Comment: yes and i have changed codes to do so  and can u see the codes edit and tell me what i m doing wrong?

Comment: Remove "fragment." from the startActivityResult() statement, that i have modified in your question

Comment: removed but still not getting called

Comment: Make sure you called setResult(RESULT_OK) in both Payment cancel and payment success condition